# How to avoid compilation error while referring common jar files?

Tags: java, tomcat, web-applications, jetty

I have a common jar that needs to be placed in Tomcat / Jetty lib folder, so that all the WAR files will be able to access the JAR. My code gets compilation error as it could not link to the JAR. How to access the common JAR that is placed in the lib folder of the server?

Comment: Is it a Maven project? If that is the case you can use 'provided' scope in pom file to access those jar files.

Comment: If not you can compile against the in-situ jar file

Comment: No it is not maven project. How to link the common jar?

Comment: I have linked jarA to web project as Project -> Properties -> Add external JAR. This avoids compilation error in eclipse. I have placed the jarA in lib/ext folder. How to access jar in lib/ext? is this done through code or server config?

Answer (score 0):

I have used Manifest file in WAR to link to the external JAR. In manifest file I specified the external JARs as, "Class-Path: ". To avoid compilation error, I linked the external JARs as "Java BuildPath -> Libraries". Though the JARs are linked using above method, only the JARs found in "lib" folder of the server is used by the application :-)